# How to determine if our sites have 301 redirection

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, magento, redirect, http-status-code-301

The short version of my question may be: Do Magento and Wordpress have 301 www redirection?
(e.g. http://www.site.com -> http://site.com)

Of course, our installs are accessible from www or non-www domains, but I'm not 100% that this is *301* redirection.

I know there are plenty of tutorials on how to set up 301 redirection, but my company is asking me if we already have this with our sites, one in magento and two others in wordpress.

I told them I assume these already have it built in, as they are powerful, popular CMS tools.

Looking in the HTACCESS file, I don't see anything that gives it away, so I'm not sure where to look.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress doesn't come with 301 redirects by default. There is a great [redirection plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/) that handles 301 redirects and tracks 404's so that you can add redirects for them and has a nice UI.

For Magento a simple google search showed me how to setup a 301.

> 1. Navigate to Catalog > Url Rewrite Management
> 2. Click the “Add Urlrewrite” button
> 3. Select “Custom” from the “Create Urlrewrite” drop-down menu
> 4. The “Urlrewrite Information” form would be completed thusly:

```
ID Path: old-url.html 
Request Path: old-url.html 
Target Path: http://www.domain.com/new-url.html Redirect: Permanent(301)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is nothing shown in your .htaccess sample that would be redirecting between "www" and non-"www".  However, something like this may also be done in the base Apache configuration (`.config` files), and not necessarily in `.htaccess` files.

If a 301 redirect is being performed, you should see a `RewriteRule` with a trailing `[R=301]` flag somewhere, for it to be a true "301 redirect".

Answer (score 1):

If your virtual host is set up to work with both domain names, i.e...

```
ServerName host.com
ServerAlias www.host.com
```

Then both will resolve to your site.

In Magento, when you set the domain name in System->Configuration->Web->Unsecure/Secure, this will be the domain name used in the site, and it will send a 301 if you use another domain name.

In other words, if you want to use domain.com and set Magento up to use this domain, any requests to www.domain.com will be answered with a 301 to domain.com.

You can always test this using [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) with the -I option (headers only). It will show you the response headers and any redirects that are taking place.

```
curl -I www.domain.com
```